# Does Artifactory support a concept of SNAPSHOT artifact expiration?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am using Artifactory to support an enterprise multi-module project. Often, we change the names of modules and the associated dependencies in POM files are not updated to use the new module name. Because SNAPSHOT dependencies are not automatically cleaned up on a regular interval, these old module references can stay there for months. I discovered a few when I migrated Artifactory to another server and the old module dependencies resulted in build errors. I am building these SNAPSHOT artifacts nightly using Jenkins so I would like some way to automate cleaning up the SNAPSHOT artifacts.

Does Artifactory (or another artifact server such as Nexus) support a concept where if a SNAPSHOT artifact is older than X days, the artifact is deleted? Is there another way to automate artifact server cleanup to accomplish what I want to do? The only thing I can think of is to create a cron job to clear out libs-snapshot-local on a regular interval before the nightly build starts. Has someone already built this capability?

Comment: Artifactory's built-in snapshot cleanup goes by quantity, not age. But as Gareth mentioned, it's fairly easy to implement as a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Artifactory doesn't have an automated way to delete modules that are older than a certain value.  At my shop we've written a Groovy client that uses [Artifactory's REST API](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s%2bREST%2bAPI&ei=v07GUK6XHs7migLu1YCQAw&usg=AFQjCNExiwGbw6IwKF4_bsOHfak7mH384Q) to do exactly this.

Note that, if your artifacts are shared libraries, you need to be careful that nothing depends on them before you delete them.  Our script takes this into account, too.

If you're interested in following up, post a comment and I'll see if it's OK to share our script with you.

Comment: If you're able to share the plugin, perhaps you could also include it in JFrog's sample plugin repository (https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins)?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be a [user plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins). You can write a simple Groovy script that will run in Artifactory itself (as opposite to remote invocation by REST Gareth proposed) on a scheduled basis, [searching for artifacts not downloaded for a long time](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/2.6.5/artifactory-papi-2.6.5-javadoc.jar!/org/artifactory/search/Searches.html#artifactsNotDownloadedSince%28java.util.Calendar,%20java.util.Calendar,%20java.lang.String...%29) and [deleting them](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/2.6.5/artifactory-papi-2.6.5-javadoc.jar!/org/artifactory/repo/Repositories.html#delete%28org.artifactory.repo.RepoPath%29).

Answer (score 2):

I've made a Ruby script to delete artifacts which aren't download for X days. The way it works just like what JBaruch mentioned in his answer.

It isn't a plugin. It works with Artifactory Open Source. Plugin is only supported by Artifactory Pro.

The source code: https://gist.github.com/aleung/5203736